# GridSearchCV(): ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: scikit-learn

I get the ValueError in the title when I try to perform a GridsearchCV on an MLP classifier. Ofcourse I checked if any of np.inf or np.nan exist in my dataset, but they dont:

```
    print(np.any(np.isnan(X)))
```

returns False

```
    print(np.all(np.isfinite(X)))
```

Returns True

I also casted all my values to np.float64

```
X = X.values.astype(np.float64)
Y = Y.values
```

My scikit-learn version is 0.22.2.post1 (latest)

**The code i'm trying to execute:**

```
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint

hiddenlayers = [(sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),), (sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),)]
alpha_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 1)


param_grid_MLP = [{'solver': ['lbfgs'],
                   'hidden_layer_sizes': hiddenlayers,
                   'activation': ['identity','tanh', 'relu', 'logistic'],
                   'alpha': alpha_range
                  },
                 {'solver': ['sgd'],
                  'hidden_layer_sizes': hiddenlayers,
                   'activation': ['identity','tanh', 'relu', 'logistic'],
                   'alpha': alpha_range,
                  'learning_rate':['constant','invscaling','adaptive']
                  },
                 {'solver': ['adam'],
                  'hidden_layer_sizes': hiddenlayers,
                   'activation': ['identity','tanh', 'relu', 'logistic'],
                   'alpha': alpha_range
                  }]

mlp = MLPClassifier(random_state=0)
cross_validation = StratifiedKFold(5)

# scoring = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 
#            'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
#            'Recall':make_scorer(recall_score,pos_label='crafted'),
#            'Precision': make_scorer(precision_score,pos_label='crafted')}

scoring = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 
           'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
            'Recall':make_scorer(recall_score,pos_label='crafted')}

grid_search_MLP = GridSearchCV(estimator=mlp, 
            param_grid=param_grid_MLP, 
            scoring=scoring,cv=cross_validation.split(X_train,y_train),
            refit='Recall',
            n_jobs=-1,
            verbose=True)

grid_search_MLP.fit(X_train,y_train)

print('Best score: {}'.format(grid_search_MLP.best_score_))
print('Best index: {}'.format(grid_search_MLP.best_index_))
print('Best parameters: {}'.format(grid_search_MLP.best_params_))

mlp = grid_search_MLP.best_estimator_
mlp
```

**The full error traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 608, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 544, in _fit_and_score
    test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 591, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 87, in __call__
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 332, in _score
    return self._sign * self._score_func(y, y_pred, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 369, in roc_auc_score
    y_score = check_array(y_score, ensure_2d=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 578, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 60, in _assert_all_finite
    msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: Where do you get your array from? A csv file ? How do you build it ? Can you make a print of it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you might have a corrupted value in your array, or a non numeric value. Try to check if there are other types in your array, before  transforming to float. Try also to find the min and max value in your array, that might help to find the value which raises the error.

Answer (score 0):

try giving verbose a large number, or run that 3 parts of grid one by one. if you realize `sgd` gives the problem, its probably explained here [MLPRegressor error when solver sgd is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197518/mlpregressor-error-when-solver-sgd-is-used)